# AngularJs views routing doesn't work

Tags: html, angularjs, routes

Trying to make simple routing on AngularJs. I added ng-app to html once. And all my javascript takes okace in 1 file. My ng-view component doesn't show anything. There is my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app">
<head>
  <link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="js/lib/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/lib/angular-route.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#/">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#/gallery">Gallery</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#/contribute">Contribute Photo</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div ng-view></div>
</body>
</html>
```

My main.js file

```
const app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute'])
    .config(function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl: '/pages/home.html',
                controller: 'homeController'
            })
            .when('/gallery', {
                templateUrl: '/pages/gallery.html',
                controller: 'galleryController'
            })
            .when('/contribute', {
                templateUrl: '/pages/contribute.html',
                controller: 'galleryController'
            });
    })
    .controller('homeController', function($scope) {
    })
    .controller('galleryController', function ($scope) {
    });
```

I tryied to use js libs from websites and localy but it didn't help. Compare with examples in the Internet, but everything i find is similar to mine. In my template files i just put some h1 headers.[There is my project directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4BUK4.jpg)

Comment: remove # tag from the url

Comment: Doesn't help. No difference

Comment: Try removing the leading slash from the templateUrl values. Meaning, try templateUrl:'pages/contribute.html' - Check if this helps

Comment: @VladislavRusak explain more what happens, "it doesn't show anything" is too vague. Do you have any errors in the console? Does it redirect you anywhere, like a 404 page? etc.

Comment: Yes, removing slash helps me, Thank u a lot! So stupid mistake from me)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is working code:
https://plnkr.co/edit/oHY8XMKk5Na13wU5JtNg?p=preview

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular-route.js"></script>

<body ng-app="myApp">

<p><a href="#/!">Main</a></p>

<a href="#!red">Red</a>
<a href="#!green">Green</a>
<a href="#!blue">Blue</a>

<div ng-view></div>

<script>
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngRoute"]);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/", {
        template : "<br/><h1>page1</h1>"
    })
    .when("/red", {
        template : "<br/><h1>page2</h1>"
    })
    .when("/green", {
        template : "<br/><h1>page3</h1>"
    })
    .when("/blue", {
        template : "<br/><h1>Put your template url by by page url</h1>"
    });
});
</script>

<p>Click on the links to navigate to "red.htm", "green.htm", "blue.htm", or back to "main.htm"</p>
</body>
</html>
```